# Why did Alaksiej Zarycki dedicate "The Heart" to Pimien Pancanka?

Tags: poetry, belarusian-language, like-water-like-fire, pimien-pancanka, alaksiej-zarycki

*The Heart* by Alaksiej Zarycki starts off by saying:

> A miser I,
> The greatest of misers
> All that I can find in
> My heart I am hiding.
> Dreams from youth rising,
> Battle's loud thunder,
> Fortune'd bright wonder,
> Greatness of our country,
> Her dear bounty,
> The light of her glory poured - 
> All this in my heart I have stored.

The poem is labeled as being "for Pimien Pancanka" (another Belarusian poet whose works also appear in *Like Water, like Fire*). How did the authors know each other? What was the nature of their relationship? And why was this particular poem dedicated to Pancanka?